# How to share a button group's state across multiple tabs using Bootstrap 5 and JQuery (or pure JS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I am developing a tabbed web page using Bootstrap 5 nav-tabs for the front end and JQuery for the back end (I think, I am not normally a web developer so I don't know if my terminology is correct).

I want to display a single radio button group on all tabs, and when clicking on a new tab, the state of the button group will be updated in the new tab to what it was on the previous tab.  So essentially I want the state of the button group to persist across tabs.

This is where I'm at currently.  I have both tabs displaying the button group, but only the second tab has the first button checked by default, and the state of the group does not transfer between tabs.  I think I need additional javascript that will read the button group state from Tab First and update/display it on Tab Second on tab change, rather than load shared-btn-group.html into both tabs, but I do not know how to accomplish this with JQuery or pure JavaScript.  Any ideas?

Code:

**shared-btn-group.html**

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button1" autocomplete="off" checked />
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="button1">B1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button2" autocomplete="off" />
  <label class="btn  btn-outline-primary" for="button2">B2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button3" autocomplete="off" />
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="button3">B3</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button4" autocomplete="off" />
  <label class="btn  btn-outline-primary" for="button4">B4</label>
</div
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" name="tab-first" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#pane-first" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pane-first" aria-selected="true">Tab First</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" name="tab-second" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#pane-second" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pane-second" aria-selected="false">Tab Second</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent" >
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pane-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-first">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="container-first"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pane-second" role="tab-panel" aria-labelledby="tab-second">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="container-second"></div>
      </div>

    <!-- Get JQuery -->
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
              integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Get Bootstrap bundle -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // load shared button group into the first container in Tab First
        $(function(){
        $("#container-first").load("shared-btn-group.html"); 
        });

        // load shared button group into the second container in Tab Second
        $(function(){
        $("#container-second").load("shared-btn-group.html"); 
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading shared-btn-group.html (the widget) multiple times, creating elements with duplicated id attributes which is invalid.

The solution is to move the widget to the new pane when a tab is clicked (it will remain in whatever state it is in at that time). Thankfully, BS provides [events you can hook into in order to make this easier](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#events).

In the following snippet, I have added a `div.shared-btn-group-wrapper` as a placeholder element in each pane where the widget will appear. To make the example work I have put shared-btn-group.html directly into the first pane. When a tab is clicked we find the identifier of the new pane and then append the widget to the placeholder within that pane.

```js
$(function() {
  const $sharedBtnGroup = $('#button1').closest('.btn-group')

  $('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('hide.bs.tab', function(event) {
    let newPaneId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('bs-target')
    let $newSlot = $(newPaneId).find('.shared-btn-group-wrapper')

    $sharedBtnGroup.appendTo($newSlot)
    console.log(newPaneId)
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" name="tab-first" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#pane-first" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pane-first" aria-selected="true">Tab First</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" name="tab-second" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#pane-second" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pane-second" aria-selected="false">Tab Second</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pane-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-first">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container-first">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="shared-btn-group-wrapper">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button1" autocomplete="off" checked />
              <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="button1">B1</label>

              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button2" autocomplete="off" />
              <label class="btn  btn-outline-primary" for="button2">B2</label>

              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button3" autocomplete="off" />
              <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="button3">B3</label>

              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="shared-btn-group" id="button4" autocomplete="off" />
              <label class="btn  btn-outline-primary" for="button4">B4</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pane-second" role="tab-panel" aria-labelledby="tab-second">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container-second">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="shared-btn-group-wrapper">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Get JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Get Bootstrap bundle -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```